# What is the fastest way to optimize a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, innodb

I've ran many different DELETE queries against many tables in the huge database (hundreds of millions records). What would be faster - to run OPTIMIZE TABLE against each modified table. Or just to mysqldump into the file and then restore back from the file?

Think that this will be equal. Just mysqldump | mysql will be faster ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OPTIMISE TABLE` will be faster as the data will not have to be converted to a textual format used by `mysqldump` and then digested by the `mysql` command line client.

If you are using `InnoDB` then you can do another trick,

```
ALTER TABLE $table ENGINE innodb;
```

This will rebuild the table by copying all the rows to a new table space and replacing the current table once done. However, while this is happening, the original table will not block readers. Writers will, of course, be blocked from updating until the operation is complete.

Comment: Just to be clear, this works if the table is already InnoDB?

Comment: This command will convert the table format to InnoDB, one of the side effects of running it on a table that is already in InnoDB format, is that it will be rebuilt.

Comment: [*For InnoDB tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE is mapped to ALTER TABLE, which rebuilds the table to update index statistics and free unused space in the clustered index.*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html)